# Java Spring MVC + Jetty Websocket Incompatible Method Signatures

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty, spring-websocket

I am trying to implement's Spring's integration of websockets with Jetty. In the Spring docs it says that if we are using Jetty, we need to

> "supply a pre-configured Jetty WebSocketServerFactory and plug that
>   into Spring’s DefaultHandshakeHandler"

This is the example they provided in the Spring docs (XML configuration)

```
<bean id="handshakeHandler" class="org.springframework...DefaultHandshakeHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="upgradeStrategy"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="upgradeStrategy" class="org.springframework...JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy">
        <constructor-arg ref="serverFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="serverFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty...WebSocketServerFactory">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty...WebSocketPolicy">
                <constructor-arg value="SERVER"/>
                <property name="inputBufferSize" value="8092"/>
                <property name="idleTimeout" value="600000"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

As you can see, they are creating a WEbSocketServerFactory and passing in a WebSocketPolicy. However, the latest Jetty version 9.4.8 has a different method signature.

```
WebSocketServerFactory​(javax.servlet.ServletContext context, WebSocketPolicy policy)
```

In addition to a WebSocketPolicy, it also needs a ServletContext. And I am getting an error when I run my application with Jetty because of the method signature mismatch. I noticed that in older versions of Jetty, the WebSocketServerFactory only takes the WebSocketPolicy (which would make the above Spring configuration work), but I do not want to downgrade my Jetty version.

I was wondering if anyone knew how I could pass in the ServletContext within an XML configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
<constructor-arg type="javax.servlet.ServletContext"/>
```

to your serverFactory bean definition, and let Spring inject it automatically.